# Cannot display array objects in html in angular 4 ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[My array structure in my application](http://sesame-dmh.rimes.int/index.php/api_fc/advisory/town/3)

I get above array structure in my application and then I assign it to my variable as follows:

```
     `
    .subscribe(data => (
        this.user = data,
        console.log('rain', this.user)
    ));`
```

but I am not able to display it in HTML. I tried to display following way

```
` <ion-option  *ngFor="let users of user">{{users[0].pentad1.
 rainfall}}</ion-option>
               </ion-select> `
```

Can some one please help me with this??

Comment: please show the function completely.

Comment: this.api.get_pentad1(param)
        .subscribe(data => (
            this.user = data[0],
            console.log('rain', this.user)
        )); my function only consists this

Comment: @user7500984 i think this line should be {{users[0].pentad1.
 rainfall}} according to your object response

Comment: yes baseer you are correct. Stackoverflow was giving me error so I had to remove it.  My HTML is <ion-option *ngFor="let users of user">{{users[0].pentad1.rainfall}}</ion-option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Array structure, to display the rainfall, I would suggest you to use a pipe.

Run the following command to generate a pipe

```
 ionic generate pipe rainfall
```

> [What is a pipe?](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

In your component

```
...
public users : any = [];
...
.subscribe(res => {
    this.users = res;
 });
```

transform function in the pipe

```
transform(value: string, index: number) {
    const key = `pentad${index+1}`;
    return value[key].rainfall;
}
```

In your html

```
<ion-select>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index;" [value]="user">{{user | rainfall: i}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**Note:** Put the **PipesModule** in the **imports** array of your components module.

Comment: do i need to create a pipe for each the array objects that i want to display??

Comment: If your object structure matches, then you can reuse this pipe. Else you can create different pipes for different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *ngFor instead of For to display it in HTML

Comment: yes i have use *ngFor. I had to remove it from here cause it was not letting me post with *ngFOr.  My HTML is <ion-option *ngFor="let users of user">{{users[0].pentad1.rainfall}}</ion-option>

Answer (score 0):

In the api file use promise,

```
 get_pentad1(param){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      this.http.method(url, param)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error => {
            resolve(error.statusText);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

use `.then()` function to get the response from the api
as

```
this.api.get_pentad1(param).then(data => { this.user = data[0] } );
```

Comment: yes i have use *ngFor. I had to remove it from here cause it was not letting me post with *ngFOr. My HTML is <ion-option *ngFor="let users of user">{{users[0].pentad1.rainfall}}</ion-option>

Comment: i got "error trying to diff ' object object '. only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: try `this.api.get_pentad1(param).then(data => { console.log(data)} ); `. what do you see in the console?

Comment: Response {_body: "[{"pentad1":{"rainfall":"7.77","humidity":"91.39",…_days":"5","spell_type":"Wet","pentad_id":"44"}}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: try `this.api.get_pentad1(param).then(data => { this.user = data } ); `

Comment: the html page still gives me error trying to diff obejct object when i try to view the array in <ion-option *ngFor="let users of user">{{users[0].pentad1.rainfall}}</ion-option>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

TS File:

```
public user : any = [];


.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.user = data;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<ion-select>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let users of user">

     <span *ngIf="users && users.pentad1"> {{users.pentad1.rainfall}}</span>
     <span *ngIf="users && users.pentad2"> {{users.pentad2.rainfall}}</span>
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

You might have to change "pentad1" and "pentad2" in order to be consistent just a suggestion

Comment: got "error trying to diff ' object object '. only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: You should define your user object as  public user : any =  []; and then assign the value as   this.user = data; (as you are already doing).

Comment: Yes I have done that in the initial stage itself. without declaring it, its not possible to do this.user = data. any even after that i have the above error

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand your last comment. I have tested the whole code by myself and its working fine for me. Just declare user object as an array.

Comment: please check my array structure